# Error committing 10k records to Janus graph with cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, janusgraph

I'm fetching around 10 million records from a oracle DB and trying to persist those to Janus graph with Cassandra as storage backend [using Spark framework].

When i tried iterating the records in a loop and tried to commit every 10k, I'm getting the below error

```
 ERROR StandardJanusGraph: Could not commit transaction [1] due to storage exception in commit
    org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception
```

When i tried to get only the first 1L record from Oracle and committed every 1K, then its working fine.

Can someone help me to resolve this error? Appreciate your help. Thank you!!

**Update:**

```
WARN  [ReadStage-3] 2019-09-29 08:39:28,327 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:167 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-3,5,main]: {}
WARN  [MemtableFlushWriter:17] 2019-09-29 09:09:40,843 NativeLibrary.java:304 - open(/var/lib/cassandra/data/circuit_equipment/system_properties-eeef4cb0e29711e9af61a34111381c19, O_RDONLY) failed, errno (2).
ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:17] 2019-09-29 09:09:40,846 LogTransaction.java:272 - Transaction log [md_txn_flush_de900e80-e298-11e9-af61-a34111381c19.log in /var/lib/cassandra/data/circuit_equipment/system_properties-eeef4cb0e29711e9af61a34111381c19] indicates txn was not completed, trying to abort it now
ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:17] 2019-09-29 09:09:40,847 LogTransaction.java:275 - Failed to abort transaction log [md_txn_flush_de900e80-e298-11e9-af61-a34111381c19.log in /var/lib/cassandra/data/circuit_equipment/system_properties-eeef4cb0e29711e9af61a34111381c19]
ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:17] 2019-09-29 09:09:40,848 LogTransaction.java:222 - Unable to delete /var/lib/cassandra/data/circuit_equipment/system_properties-eeef4cb0e29711e9af61a34111381c19/md_txn_flush_de900e80-e298-11e9-af61-a34111381c19.log as it does not exist, see debug log file for stack trace
ERROR [MemtablePostFlush:9] 2019-09-29 09:09:40,849 CassandraDaemon.java:228 - Exception in thread Thread[MemtablePostFlush:9,5,main]
WARN  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-09-29 09:09:40,849 StorageService.java:4591 - Caught exception while waiting for memtable flushes during shutdown hook
ERROR [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-09-29 09:09:40,931 AbstractCommitLogSegmentManager.java:308 - Failed to force-recycle all segments; at least one segment is still in use with dirty CFs.
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 09:09:44,580 NativeLibrary.java:187 - Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 09:09:44,581 StartupChecks.java:169 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 09:09:44,591 SigarLibrary.java:174 - Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : false,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : true, nproc limit adequate? : true
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 09:09:44,593 StartupChecks.java:311 - Maximum number of memory map areas per process (vm.max_map_count) 65530 is too low, recommended value: 1048575, you can change it with sysctl.
WARN  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2019-09-29 09:12:12,841 CompressionParams.java:383 - The sstable_compression option has been deprecated. You should use class instead
WARN  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2019-09-29 09:12:12,842 CompressionParams.java:334 - The chunk_length_kb option has been deprecated. You should use chunk_length_in_kb instead
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 12:59:57,584 NativeLibrary.java:187 - Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 12:59:57,585 StartupChecks.java:169 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 12:59:57,599 SigarLibrary.java:174 - Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : false,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : true, nproc limit adequate? : true
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 12:59:57,602 StartupChecks.java:311 - Maximum number of memory map areas per process (vm.max_map_count) 65530 is too low, recommended value: 1048575, you can change it with sysctl.
root@f451df425ca8:/var/log/cassandra#
```

Comment: are there details in C* or janus logs on what the backend exception is?

Comment: Please run the following `grep 'ERROR\|WARN' /var/log/cassandra/system.log`, and put the output in your question. The system.log location might vary, so change to the appropriate value.

Comment: @PedroGordo Attached the cassandra ERROR/WARN log in the question as an update. Can you please check!

Comment: @PedroGordo Thanks for the reply. Is it enough to set the vm.max_map_count = 1048575 in  /etc/sysctl.conf because could not find the cassandra.conf file in the below path - /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf                                                       
--To disable swap in cassandra - is it fine to clear the /etc/fstab

Comment: @PedroGordo -> Changed the cassandra.conf in /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf as well as  vm.max_map_count = 1048575 in /etc/sysctl.conf.Unable to reboot the server using the command sudo sysctl -p saying -> sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count":Read-only file system and also unable to run the sudo swapoff --all (Swap disable) saying -> swapoff : Not superuser.

Comment: @Sruthi if you run `sudo whoami`, what do you get?

Comment: @PedroGordo -> for more info am using docker container

Comment: @PedroGordo ran the sudo whoami , gives root

Comment: @Sruthi it might be better if you create a new question on SO for that issue. The problems you're having in disabling swap, are not related to Cassandra.

Answer (score 2):

From these messages, you should disable swap (this is actually one of the main recommendations in Cassandra):

```
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 09:09:44,580 NativeLibrary.java:187 - Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 09:09:44,591 SigarLibrary.java:174 - Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : false,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : true, nproc limit adequate? : true
```

You should also change `max_map_count`. You can use [this guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configRecommendedSettings.html) to set the other values for production environments. From this message:

```
WARN  [main] 2019-09-29 12:59:57,602 StartupChecks.java:311 - Maximum number of memory map areas per process (vm.max_map_count) 65530 is too low, recommended value: 1048575, you can change it with sysctl.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pedro Gordo                                                                                    
Step 1:  We need to add the vm.max_map_count = 1048575 in /etc/sysctl.conf.                  Step 2: Could not find the path for cassandra.conf path in the below folder. 
 /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf.                                                                                Is it enough to add the step1 for my problem

Comment: @Sruthi I think `/etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf` changes the location slightly depending on your OS, but I'm not sure.
More importantly, don't forget to turn off swap.